Referencing custom config file based on condition serverless yml
I have serverless framework setup to deploy lambda function. I have two files containing custom settings (dev_config.yml and prod_config.yml)
I want to reference either of the custom setting config file (dev_config.yml or prod_config.yml) based on the stage I pass as parameter to serverless.
my serverless deploy command will be:
sls deploy --stage dev
Is it possible to add condition in custom section something like below, so that serverless references dev_config.yml file if stage is dev and prod_config.yml file if stage is passed as prod
custom:
  configFile:
    preprod: dev.yml
    prod: prod.yml
  defaultStg: preprod
  serverlessIfElse:
    - If: '"${self:provider.stage}" == "prod"'
      Set:
        custom.config: ${file(sls/config/${self:custom.configFile.prod})}
      ElseSet:
        custom.config: ${file(sls/config/${self:custom.configFile.preprod})}
.....
functions:
  SizingLambda:
  name: ${self:provider.stage}-Sizing-lambda
  description: Lambda to integrate with the downstream system
  handler: js/index.handler
  reservedConcurrency: ${self:custom.config.concurrencyLimit}
.....

Please let me know how we can achieve this. Thank you in advance.
Note: I tried with serverless-plugin-ifelse which is not working.
